# Lookup names in large texts

Tags: database, search, text, names

What is the best way to parse large texts (5000 words and more), searching names, that are stored in a database? The texts will be multi lingual.

My first idea is a rather naive approach, taking all words beginning with a big letter and compare them against the database. But this tends to fail in texts containing lowercase letters only.

**Edit**
The texts are not static, but dynamic (e.g. web sites)

Best

Macs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use your RDBMS's built-in full-text indexing capabilities.

[Full-Text Search (SQL Server)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx)

[MySQL Full-Text Search Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html)

[Full Text Indexing using Oracle Text](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/9i/FullTextIndexingUsingOracleText9i.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Aho-Corasick algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho-Corasick_algorithm), and construct a dictionary with the names that you are trying to match. It's linear in the number of tokens in the text plus the number of matched names.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a dictionary of names.

Or you can try http://www.opencalais.com/ that knows quite a large collection of names.

Comment: Wow, thanks for that one. It's really an option beneath the other answers :)

Answer (score 0):

I made a method for replacing multiple strings in a large text here: [A better way to replace many strings - obfuscation in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/711753/a-better-way-to-replace-many-strings-obfuscation-in-c). Perhaps you can use the same principle.