# Known list of "filler" words; how to rip good keywords using C#?

Tags: c#

If I've got a block of text, in English, what's the best method of clearing away all the "filler" words like "the, it, or, we, us", etc... leaving only viable words to be considered the real, core, content of the text?

I'm brainstorming a way to automatically tie blocks of text together based on how similar they are in keyword composition.

I can't be the first one to imagine this. Is there a popular, effective way this can be accomplished using C#?

**Update**

I am trying to essentially link one block of text, to n "related" blocks of text, where the primary "content" is so similar that it could be considered additional information to the text it is related to...

Comment: Although I am not a native English speaker, I doubt that "the" is just a filler word. Consider: “No, not _the_ Zaphod Beeblebrox, _a_ Zaphod Beeblebrox. Didn't you hear I come in six-packs now?”

Comment: @Vlad - I would say it is filler in the sense that it does not help at all to infer the topic of a sentence.

Comment: partial list of words and phrases you'd want to eliminate: http://www.smart-words.org/transition-words.html

Comment: @Rotem: well, without _the_, the whole point of the sentence would be completely unclear.

Comment: @Vlad The question is if the OP is trying to infer the meaning of a sentence or the topic. Even without the the, I can infer the sentence deals with Zaphod BeebleBrox and/or six-packs.

Comment: Phwew, re-reading my update, did I just make my thought more difficult to understand? :) @Rotem, yes, I am (in a sense) trying to infer the meaning of the text. I'm not trying to remove the filler words, which could have an impact on humans reading the text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This thing is called [**stop words**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stop_words) - words that are usually<sup>1</sup> not essential for understanding the data, and are removed by indexers.

Almost any [Information Retrieval](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Information_retrieval) system I am aware of implements a tokenizer that filter these words.

I am familiar with java's lucene, that has [StandardAnalyzer](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_0_1/api/all/org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/StandardAnalyzer.html) that does it for you, but I assume this analyzer also exists in [lucene.net](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/) - you may want to track it and use it.

You might also be interested in [stemming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemming), which is also done in lucene by [EnglishAnalyzer](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_1_0/api/contrib-analyzers/org/apache/lucene/analysis/en/EnglishAnalyzer.html) for instance.

---

(1) Why usually? In sarcasm ditactors, for example - it seems (empirically) that stop words are critical to get good results.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that the poster does want to filter out stop words (as opposed to some other hand crafted list of words), however the same techniques used to filter out stop words could certainly be used to filter out any other list of words.

Comment: @Justin: The java interface (And I can only assume also the C#) of the analyzers in lucene - allows one to manually gives a list of stop words to be used by the analyzer.

Comment: @amit, thank you! I've got some reading to do now, but this looks like what I'm wanting. I simply want to relate blocks of text to each other, based on their real content (not the stop words). Thanks!

Comment: @amit, also I'm using RavenDB in my project... which I believe uses Lucene.net heavily. Perhaps I could knock out a lot of this work on the DB end. Hmm...

Answer (score 3):

If you want this to be done in a large scale and if the filter words are going to increase constanly, then you can use NLPs like [openNLP](http://opennlp.apache.org)

You can use it to remove the prepositions,connectors etc...

Comment: Thanks for the link... looks like some deep reading. I appreciate the share!

Answer (score 2):

Create a list of 'filler words'. Replace all occurrences of any element in this list of the original block of text with String.Empty.

[string replace using a List<string>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3712317/string-replace-using-a-liststring)

Comment: But what if that filler word is inside a good word? It will also get replaced. like words `the` and `themes`?

Comment: Split them first? Answer updated to include link that elaborates on this.

Comment: This is what I imagined right away... but I wanted to ask just in case there was a better way. Thanks!

Comment: @Chad - not a problem. I like the look of atmybase.com a lot mate, looking good. There's a bug on the search (when the textbox is empty) but I'm assuming you know that. Could be a winner tho, don't know of anything else like that.

Comment: Thanks @Daniel... the next version I'm working on now will integrate Foursquare, Instagram, Facebook, and SocialCam to help "describe" a location (and make it "social").

The text part I'm working on now is to make it so articles of information the military members share about their base relate together automatically without requiring them to associate it themselves (and relate better than "they're in the same category"). Thanks again!