# Fastest way to find/replace in a large string

Tags: c#, string, performance, replace, stringbuilder

I have a function that does a lot of finding and replacing on strings, using Regex and other string processing functions. Essentially I'm looping through a string, and adding the resulting data into a `StringBuilder` so its faster than modifying the string itself. Is there a faster way?

Comment: Without any code of your current approach we cannot suggest a better one. But even then it sounds as if you want to post it better at [`codereview.stackexchange.com`](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: it would help if you would show us what you have so far!

Comment: http://www.dotnetperls.com/regex-groups may it help you

Comment: If you are doing multiple replaces in one string, perhaps this would be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/711753/a-better-way-to-replace-many-strings-obfuscation-in-c-sharp/712058#712058

Comment: U can't modify a String in C# because Strings are immutable.

Answer (score 2):

> Essentially I'm looping through a string, and adding the resulting
>   data into a StringBuilder so its faster than modifying the string
>   itself. Is there a faster way?

- [`StringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) class is faster when you want to concatenate some strings into a loop.
- If you're concatening an array [`String.Concat()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xb636w5t.aspx) is faster bacause it has some overloads which accept arrays.
- else use simply the `+` operator if you have to do something like: `string s = "text1" + "text2" + "text3";` or use `String.Concat("text1", "text2", "text3");`.

For more info look here: [Concatenate String Efficiently](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/stringbuilder.html).

**EDIT :**

The `+` operator compiles to a call to `String.Concat()` as said *usr* in his comment.

Comment: The `+` operator compiles to a call to `String.Concat`.